# object property coming up as undefined

Tags: javascript, object, properties, undefined

Through recursion i'm adding data to the obj['prop'] property in forms of db query results.

```js
let obj = {};

if (obj['prop'] == undefined) {
  obj['prop'] = {};
}

console.log(obj);
```

Why isn't this working?
I've tried this too.

```
if(!obj['prop']){
 obj['prop'] = {}
}
```

I know it has nothing to do with the presented error...

However i'm applying values with multiple nested properties to an object.

```
obj['prop']['prop2'] = results
```

And it didn't allow me to so I applied the property inside the object before adding further nested properties. But it's not working. It's still coming up with property 'prop' undefined.

My function:

```
 posts: function(request, cb){
            application = (request.query.application) ? request.query.application : "*";
            type = (request.query.type) ? request.query.type : "*";
            wall = (request.query.wall) ? request.query.wall : "*";
            db.query(
                "SELECT * FROM Client.Posts WHERE Application = ? AND Wall_Type = ? AND Wall_Name = ?;",
                [
                    application,
                    type,
                    wall
                ],
                function(error, posts){
                    if(posts.length == 0){
                        cb(posts);
                    }else{
                        repliesDone = false;
                        likesDone = false;
                        commentsDone = false;
                        commentLikesDone = false;
                        repliesLikesDone = false;
                        function PostRecursionComments(posts, length, i){
                            if(posts[i]['DATA'] == undefined){
                                posts[i]['DATA'] = {};
                            }
                            db.query(
                                "SELECT * FROM Client.Comments WHERE Client.Comments.Post_ID = ?",
                                [
                                    posts[i]['ID']
                                ],
                                function(error, comments){
                                    for(i = 0; i < comments.length; i++){
                                        db.query(
                                            "SELECT * FROM Client.Likes WHERE Type = 'Comment' AND TypeID = ?",
                                            [
                                                comments[i]['ID']
                                            ],
                                            function(error, commentLikes){
                                                commentLikesDone = true;
                                                posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][i]['DATA']['Likes'] = commentLikes;
                                            }
                                        );
                                    }
                                    posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'] = comments;
                                    if(posts.length - 1 == i){
                                        commentsDone = true;
                                    }else{
                                        i++;
                                        PostRecursionComments(posts, posts.length, i);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        PostRecursionComments(posts, posts.length, 0);
                        function CommentsRecursionReplies(comments, length, i, z, posts){
                            if(comments[z]['DATA'] == undefined){
                                comments[z]['DATA'] = {};
                            }
                            db.query(
                                "SELECT * FROM Client.Replies WHERE Client.Replies.Parent_Is_Comment = 1 AND Client.Replies.Parent_ID = ?",
                                [
                                    commentsz[z]['ID']
                                ],
                                function(error, replies){                                       
                                    for(i = 0; i < replies.length; i++){
                                        db.query(
                                            "SELECT * FROM Client.Likes WHERE Type = 'Reply' AND TypeID = ?",
                                            [
                                                replies[i]['ID']
                                            ],
                                            function(error, replyLikes){
                                                replyLikesDone = true;
                                                comments[z]['DATA']['Replies'][i]['DATA']['Likes'] = replyLikes;
                                            }
                                        );
                                    }
                                    comments[z]['DATA']['Replies'] = replies;
                                    if(posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'].length - 1 == z){
                                    }else{
                                        z++;
                                        CommentsRecursionReplies(posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'], posts['DATA']['Comments'].length, i, z, posts);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        for(i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
                            if(posts[i]['DATA']['Comments']){
                                CommentsRecursionReplies(posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'], posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'].length, i, 0, posts);
                            }
                            repliesDone = true;
                        }
                        function RepliesRecursionReplies(replies, length, i, j, z, posts){
                            if(replies[z]['DATA'] == undefined){
                                replies[z]['DATA'] = {};
                            }
                            /*  truth tables? */
                            db.query(
                                "SELECT * FROM Client.Replies WHERE Client.Replies.Parent_Is_Comment = 0 AND Client.Replies.Parent_ID = ?",
                                [
                                    posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][j]['Replies'][z]['ID']
                                ],
                                function(error, replies){
                                    if(!posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][j]['Replies'][z]['DATA']){
                                        posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][j]['Replies'][z]['DATA'] = {};
                                    }
                                    posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][j]['Replies'][z]['DATA']['Replies'] = replies;
                                    if(posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][j]['Replies'].length - z == 0){
                                        /* enumerator and properties... */
                                        repliesRepliesDone = true;
                                    }else{
                                        z++;
                                        RepliesRecursionReplies(replies, replies.length, i, j, z, posts);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        for(i = 0; i < posts[i].length; i++){
                            for(j = 0; j < posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'].length; j++){
                                RepliesRecursionReplies(posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][j]['Replies'], posts[i]['DATA']['Comments'][j]['Replies'].length, i, j, 0, posts);
                            }
                        }
                        function PostRecursionLikes(posts, length, i){
                            if(posts[i]['DATA'] == undefined){
                                posts[i]['DATA'] = {};
                            }
                            db.query(
                                "SELECT * FROM Client.Likes WHERE Type = 'Post' AND TypeID = ?",
                                [
                                    posts[i]['ID']
                                ],
                                function(error, likes){
                                    post['DATA']['Likes'] = likes;
                                    if(posts.length - 1 == i){
                                        likesDone = true;
                                    }else{
                                        i++;
                                        PostRecursionLikes(posts, posts.length, i);
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                        PostRecursionLikes(posts, posts.length, 0);
                        function callback(data){
                            if(commentsDone && repliesDone && likesDone && commentLikesDone && replikesLikesDone){
                                cb(data);
                            }else{
                                setTimeout(function(){
                                    callback(data)
                                }, 1);
                            }
                        }
                        callback(posts);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: your first snippet works as expected...

Comment: have my function.

Comment: @Rahh as you can see in the snipped, your code is working, that's why we need a REAL MINIMAL REPRODUCIBLE EXAMPLE

Comment: Just posted my example.

Comment: Also had a look at your code. Try to make the function outside the main function. It wil help in the future. And is accesible from other parts of the code to.

Answer (score -1):

It indeed doesn't work.

Thast beqause it isn't realy undefined it's empty. That means it can ether be `' '` or `null`. So try tackeling those conditions too and it should work perfect!

```js
let obj = {};

if(obj['prop'] == 'undefined' || obj['prop'] == '' || obj['prop'] == null){
  obj['prop'] = {};
}
console.log(obj['prop'])
```

Comment: U sure you added  `|| obj['prop'] == '' || obj['prop'] == null` on every occation?

Comment: Yeah i'm sure man...
What can I do? I can't recode the function in any other way... 
Unless I have a more sophisticated SQL to construct the posts object.